# How to know the effective group of a specified user without using su

Tags: linux

Sometimes I want to know the effective group of a specified user by using `su` and `groups`. Using `su` is cumbersome. So is there a way to do that without using `su`?

Answer (score 1):

Would [`id`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/id) do what you want?

```
$ id userx
uid=10987(user) gid=1234(somegroup) groups=1234(somegroup),2345(othergroup)
```

or

```
$ id userx -Gn
somegroup othergroup
```

<sup>(I'm a bit confused by the phrase *"effective group"*: processes have effective and real UIDs and GIDs, they are related to setuid/setgid executables. I haven't heard the phrase being used for users before, but apparently the man page for `id` talks about "effective group" re. `-g`. I suppose it means the primary GID.)</sup>